# Why does mod_rewrite strip the port number from my request url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy

I'm using Apache mod_proxy with mod_rewrite to mask some credentials in the query string. The logs show that the rewrite rule is working properly, but the port number (:9000) is being stripped causing the proxy to reject the URL. Aside from security lectures and anything else irrelevant to the actual question at hand, can anyone tell me what the solution might be?

**Basic example using:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)userid=fakepass(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1userid=realpass%2
```

**Original URL:** `https://domain.com:9000/somedirectory/request.jsp?userid=theuser&password=fakepass`

**Intended URL::** `https://domain.com:9000/somedirectory/request.jsp?userid=theuser&password=realpass`

**Actual result after mod_rewrite:** `https://domain.com/somedirectory/request.jsp?userid=theuser&password=realpass`

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess? Post your complete .htaccess here.

Comment: Actually working in a virtual host, but here she blows.

Was too long for SO. Here's a paste bin link. 

http://pastebin.com/0ctSEDjB

Comment: Did you ever sort this problem? i have run into the same thing...

Comment: I did. When running the page via a server (local or remote), the prefix is added automatically.

Very simple local server setup here: 

https://github.com/indexzero/http-server

Comment: I have hit the same issue - docs says that port WILL BE prepender in case of relative url - why it is not, I have no idea;/ On the other hand, example looks like `http://thishost[:thisport]` that might suggest that [thisport] is optional 0 - but if so, then what is the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

*Specify the port* in your rule. Change your .htaccess to something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)userid=fakepass(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:9000/somedirectory/request.jsp?userid=theuser&password=realpass
```